# httpd.conf VS httpd-vhosts.conf

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I added below code into httpd.conf and it works.

I remove below code and added into httpd-vhosts.conf it works also.

Why xampp provided httpd-vhosts.conf if the regular file called httpd.conf can run itself?

example:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.2:80>
    DocumentRoot "F:/server/htdocs"
    ServerName google.com
    ServerAlias www.google.com
    ErrorLog "logs/google.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/google.dec-access.log" combined

    <Directory "F:/server/htdocs">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some distributions of Apache provide some files that will be overlaid when you apply maintenance, and others that are left untouched for the user.   All config files are created equal from Apaches perspective.

Answer (score 0):

In httpd.conf You have "Include" parametr. It contains path to another conf file - in Your case it is path to httpd-vhosts.conf